# Including location dummy variables in Geographically Weighted Regression

Tags: regression, spatial

I am modelling house prices using individual observations of property sales (not polygon data).

Does it make sense to include dummy variables for postcode areas as parameters in the GWR model?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would make sense, as your model is already trying to capture these geographical patterns, i.e. the fact that property in some areas is more expensive than in others.

An exception would be if you expected there to be discontinuities across postcode boundaries. Suppose that there are two identical homes on opposite sides of the same street, but in different postcode regions. Would you expect them to have different prices? This could be the case if some postcodes are seen as more desirable than others.